# GUI for retrieving pdf documents

Tags: search, document

I have many pdf documents in my computer and I need an easy to use GUI for retrieving those that contain certain terms / phrases. So, my question is if there is any such application for ubuntu 12.04 LTS?

Answer (score 2):

There is a command-line tool `pdfgrep` which can perform your task.You can install it by
 `sudo apt-get install pdfgrep`
To search for a regular expression:

```
find /path -iname '*.pdf' -exec pdfgrep -H 'pattern' {} \;
```

where path is location for your pdf files.

There is also a GUI tool called [recoll](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/recoll) which can search documents by indexing them.

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643438/how-to-search-contents-of-multiple-pdf-files)

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but the main problem here is that it is very slow since it doesn't index the pdfs (in the background) as I would expect, so that the next time be quicker. In addition, I would prefer something more user friendly. Any idea?

Comment: I have added another GUI tool in my answer which might serve your purpose.